# Git rebase recursive branches

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I'm writing a programming course with in which I want to show how to write a program step-by-step. I thought I might use git for this purpose. The idea is to keep each lesson as a separate branch and create new branches as the course goes on.
[image: normal state]

It is all fine till I discover I've made a mistake in `lesson1`. So I go there and fix it.
[image: fix lesson 1]

Now the problem occurs: I have to rebase each and every branch. So:

```
git checkout lesson2
git rebase lesson1
```

[image]

Afterwards the same for `lesson3` and `lesson4`.
[image]

I have about 20 lessons per course so every mistake is very painful. Is there a way to automate it or at least make it easier for me?

btw. The tool I've used to create the images is available [here](http://git-school.github.io/visualizing-git/).

Comment: What's needed is a sort of en-masse multi-branch rebase. The general problem is quite difficult. Your own branches are simple and linear, which reduces the problem to one easily solved (see [Gregg's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42999905/1256452)), but which also implies that perhaps *branch names* are overkill for what you are doing. :-)

Comment: @torek - I suppose an en-masse multi-branch rebase is what `filter-branch` does, more or lees (hence the approach in my answer).  A git branch is simple enough that I'm not sure I'd call branches "overkill", especially if he has to go back and fix a "broken" lesson from time to time; but generally I guess tags would do.  (Except he'd have the same problem with tags since rebase doesn't move them...)  Did you have something simpler in mind?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: Well, no, filter-branch is *even more powerful* than that, but also clumsier to use for rebase type purposes (it's hard to get the right thing to happen to the tree, vs repeated cherry-pick = rebase, which just does the right thing). What I'm thinking of is just a straight chain of commits where "lesson N" is not a branch but just part of the commit log message, and you can then use `HEAD^{/lesson 3}` to find the commit(s).

Comment: @torek - Which is clumsier depends what you're trying to do. I actually learned about `filter-branch` when doing an operation that I originally viewed as an en-masse rebase (onto a new root commit to modify the tree throughout history) - but it turns out for histories with non-trivial branch topology the rebase is the clumsy approach. (And ultimately I used BFG, but that's neither here nor there...) I can think of only a few `filter-branch` operations that can't be expressed in terms of rebase, so I'm not sure if I agree that it's *more* powerful so much as *easier* for complex operations.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: but rebase is not simply reparent: it's diff-and-re-apply, and the new base to which you're applying may have substantive changes. If you reparent, you simply copy the original tree, so you do not get the updated base. To use filter-branch, you must not only change the parent of each commit, but also—at least potentially—its tree.

Comment: @torek - Yes, wasn't thinking about how the tree would end up in this use case.  Apparently neither were a lot of other people, because that answer drew several positive votes before I recognized the problem and got rid of it.  For *many* use cases, however, where both tools are applicable, I'd stand by my previous comments.

Answer (score 6):

So had to go back to the drawing board...

I previously suggested a simple `filter-branch` command, but this has a significant flaw.  (**tl;dr - I no longer suggest this as a use case for `filter-branch --parent-filter`; unless you care about why, you can jump to the next paragraph.**)  When you re-parent with `git filter-branch` it doesn't re-apply changes for an effective merge, but rather keeps the tree in the re-parented commit as it was (creating new diffs, essentially).  A `filter-branch` is still possible, but it requires either a `tree-filter` or an `index-filter` and this would start to get rather complex.  (If you can automate the fix in a script, then using that script as a `tree-filter` should work - possibly with a little finesse in the rev-list arguments - but let's assume for the general case that this wouldn't be so easy.  I thought about scripting a way to merge the changes from the "fix" commit into each commit in the graft, but that could result in a conflict at every turn and also isn't so easy...)

So what to do instead?  Well, a scripted approach like Libin Varghese suggests is ok if there are no conflicts, and assuming that you can iterate through the ref names in a sensible way.  But supposing there might be conflicts, there is another way...

So if you have

```
        Bfix <--(lesson1)
       /
A --- B --- C --- D --- E <--(lesson3)(HEAD)
            |
        (lesson2)
```

what you're trying to do essentially is

1) re-apply `C`, `D`, and `E` over `Bfix` as `C'`, `D'`, and `E'` (a single rebase operation)

2) move all refs from a replaced commit (`X`) to its replacement (`X'`)

Using a single rebase minimizes the amount of conflict resolution.  If you just rebase `lesson3` then you'll have

```
      (lesson1)
          |
        Bfix --- C' --- D' --- E' <--(lesson3)(HEAD)
       /
A --- B --- C <--(lesson2)
```

and then you just need rewrite the refs for branches other than the 1st and last lessons.  That means you need a mapping from "old commit `X`" to "replacement commit `X'`".

Just such a mapping is passed on stdin to .git/hooks/post-rewrite (if it exists) at the conclusion of a rebase.  So you could write a script that uses `git show-ref` to map ref (branch) names to "old" SHA1 values, then use the mapping on stdin to find the corresponding "new" SHA1 value, and call `git update-ref`.

(I am planning to provide an example script, but I'm having some trouble with hooks in my test repo; so if I have a little time later, I'll come back to this. But if you're comfortable with scripting and hooks, the above outlines what needs to be done.)

Comment: How would you find the corresponding new SHA1 value? Matching on commit message seems brittle. Inspecting the diffs wouldn't work if conflicts were solved during the rebase. Can you get the pairings from git-rebase somehow?

Comment: Oh given old tip and new tip, just collect all commits until root. This assumes a straight rebase without squashing etc.

Comment: And now I see that post-rewrite gives you a list of rewritten commits, and you can even figure out the squashes.

Comment: Added an answer with the post-rewrite hook you described.

Answer (score 1):

```
start=2
end=10
for i in {$start..$end}
do
        git checkout lesson$i
        git rebase lesson$(($i-1)) || break
done
start=$i
```

Assuming you don't have conflicts, this loop thru lesson2 thru lesson10, performing the rebase.

If rebase fails, the start is set to the point where it failed. But make sure you resolve conflicts and perform a `rebase --continue` before proceeding

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at solving the problem. You will have to fix my syntax errors, and complete the automation issues but this might be a start.

the single line

```
git rebase lesson1 lesson2
```

has the same effect as

```
git checkout lesson2
git rebase lesson1
```

you should rebase the last lesson so all the intermediate commits are transferred to the new branch at the same time.  You will have to fix any conflicts that occur.

```
git rebase lesson1 lesson4
```

then transfer the branches to new commits (if the lessons are contiguous) with commands that look something like.

```
git branch lesson2a lesson4^2
git branch lesson3a lesson4^1
```

if the branches are contiguous.  'git help revisions' shows how to find a commit using it's commit message from the given branch.

```
git branch lesson2a  lesson4^"{/Partial lesson2 commit message}"
git branch lesson3a  lesson4^"{/Partial Lesson3 commit message}"
```

once this looks right remove the old commits

```
git branch -f lesson2 lesson2a
git branch -D lesson2a
```

see 'git help rebase' for the rebase syntax

and 'git help revisions' for different ways to specify commits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post-rewrite hook as described in Mark's answer.

(I'm fairly unexperimented with shell scripting so comments welcome.)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" != "rebase" ]; then
    exit 0
fi


orig=`git rev-parse ORIG_HEAD`

while read line
do
    IFS=' '
    read -ra map <<< "$line"
    old="${map[0]}"
    new="${map[1]}"

    heads=`git show-ref | grep -e " refs/heads" | grep "$old"`

    IFS=$'\n'
    for h in $heads; do

        IFS=' '
        read -ra ref_info <<< "$h"
        ref="${ref_info[1]}"

        # Don't update original branch as this causes rebase to fail
        if [ "$old" != "$orig" ]; then
            echo "Updating '$ref' to $new"
            `git-update-ref $ref $new $old`
        fi
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR use / copy the implementation of [Graphite CLI](https://github.com/screenplaydev/graphite-cli)

This open-source CLI will perform recursive branch rebases (disclosure, I'm a contributor):
https://github.com/screenplaydev/graphite-cli

The main rebase-recursion can be seen here: https://github.com/screenplaydev/graphite-cli/blob/dfe4390baf9ce6aeedad0631e41c9f1bdc57ef9a/src/actions/fix.ts#L60

```
git rebase --onto ${parentBranch.name} ${mergeBase} ${currentBranch.name}
```

The key insight is to store branch parents in git refs, in order to recurse the DAG during operations. Without parent metadata, it would be impossible to always determine the merge-base of successive child branches.

```
const metaSha = execSync(`git hash-object -w --stdin`, {input: JSON.stringify(desc)}).toString();

execSync(`git update-ref refs/branch-metadata/${this.name} ${metaSha}`);
```

https://github.com/screenplaydev/graphite-cli/blob/dfe4390baf9ce6aeedad0631e41c9f1bdc57ef9a/src/wrapper-classes/branch.ts#L102-L109